# Estimate time to multiply two 16-bit numbers on DSPs?

Tags: signal-processing, implementation, multiplication

I am trying to procure a DSP board which allows very fast implementation of solving differential equations up to 10th order or so. The clock runs at 300 MHz (~3ns). Considering standard multiplication implementation on DSPs, how do I estimate the time to multiply two 16-bit numbers?

Thanks,
Mayank

Comment: Look up the number of clock cycles for a multiply, for your particular architecture (it should be buried somewhere in the documentation).  That will be your answer.

Comment: You probably want to know how fast the DSP board can run your specific algorithm, where multiplication is just part of the work. To roughly estimate that I suggest you compare the complexity of your algorithm to e.g. a 1024 point FFT (run both on your favorite computer). Then look up the specifications for the board, which most certainly will specify how many 1024 point FFT's can be computed pr. second. Just my simple advice.

Comment: Thank you, Oliver and Jens. :)